# Smart answer needed for strange segmentation fault on embedded ARM with posix threads

Tags: c++, linux, arm, segmentation-fault

The last couple of days I've been working on a strange segmentation fault. The following code works just fine on my PC running Linux. But using the ARM crosscompiler suppplied by the manufactor of our embedded device, it gives a segmentation fault in routine s(). The SIGSEGV occurs at the destruction of a std::string. This also happens if you pass it as a variable. However, with non STL classes (e.g. int) it all works fine.

The code is compiled using an ARM cross compiler

```
arm-linux-g++ -Wall -otest -lpthread
arm-linux-strip test
```

All suggestions are welcome!

```
using namespace std;

void *ExecuteThreadMethod(void *AThread);

class Thread
{
  private:
    pthread_t internalThread;
    sem_t finishedSemaphore;
  public:
    bool Terminated;
    Thread()
    {
      Terminated = false;
      sem_init (&finishedSemaphore, 0, 0);
    }
    ~Thread()
    {
      sem_destroy (&finishedSemaphore);
    }

    void RunSigSegv() // <----- with the try...catch it causes a SIGSEGV in routine s() below
    {
      try
      {
        while (!Terminated)
        {
          cout << "ExecuteLooped" << endl;
        }
        sem_post(&finishedSemaphore);
      }
      catch(...)
      {
      }
    }

    void RunOk() // <----- without the try...catch, it runs fine
    {
      while (!Terminated)
      {
        cout << "ExecuteLooped" << endl;
      }
      sem_post(&finishedSemaphore);
    }

    void Start()
    {
      pthread_attr_t _attr;

      pthread_attr_init(&_attr);
      pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
      pthread_create (&internalThread, &_attr, ExecuteThreadMethod, this);
    }

    void Terminate()
    {
      Terminated = true;
      sem_wait(&finishedSemaphore);
    }
};

void *ExecuteThreadMethod(void *AThread)
{
  ((Thread *)AThread)->RunSigSegv();
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

Thread _thread;

void s()
{
  string Test;
  _thread.Start();
} // <----- destruction of std::string Test causes a SIGSEGV, without try...catch in the thread this doesn't happen

void t()
{
  _thread.Terminate();
}

int main(void)
{
  s();
  t();
}
```

Comment: If you've localized the problem, take a look in that function with a disassembler.

Comment: Probably not relevant, but you have no synchronisation around `Thread::Terminated`.

Comment: Does your linker script initialize the stdcpp libraries?

Comment: @Oli: true, but I already tested with synchronisation and it still doesn't work. I guess it has something to do with stack unwinding or memory allocation routines (new and delete) that aren't thread-safe (I guess cout << also uses new and delete intern, as does the destructor of std::string)

Comment: @Leppie: what do you mean? I link with the stdc++ library (-lstdc++).

Comment: No, the linker sections like `.preinit_array` and friends that is required to initialize the stdcpp library. I know this is needed for baremetal ARM, but I would assume your linux 'init' app should do the same.

Comment: @Leppie: I'm a newbe in linker scripts. Do you have some more specific information?

Comment: @Laurens: Not really, it's very Greek to me too  :(  I just know you special initialization for C++.  Is there any other C++ app running on the device? If so, you can eliminate what I said.

Comment: No, there is no other app running on the device. I found out that the try...catch is probably the cause of this problem and I'm afraid it has to do with the (very) old compiler :-(

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `-lpthread`. This merely links with the library which provides the thread handling functions. Full threading support may require more than that, e.g. linking with a specially thread-safe version of libstdc++, or reserving a specific register for thread-local variable access.

With gcc or g++, use the `-pthread` command-line flag, both for compilation and for linking. This will instruct gcc to do whatever is necessary to enable reliable threading, including, but not limited to, adding the `-lpthread` flag when required.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem already a while ago (some years ;-)), but forgot to post the solution.

The problem was caused by a compiler bug in this ancient GCC version. Using try..catch resolves in some malicious assembler instructions that causes access violations in several situations.

I suppose it is fixed in GCC several years ago, but for us (we were forced to use this old version) the solution was to use the compiler flag `-fno-exceptions` which solved this issue.