# Try...catch causes segmentation fault on embedded ARM with posix threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, gcc, posix, arm

Today, I posted a problem about a segmentation fault after destruction of a std::string (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958196/smart-answer-needed-for-strange-segmentation-fault-on-embedded-arm-with-posix-thr)). I've stripped the code so that I don't use the STL and still have a segmentation fault sometimes.

The following code works just fine on my PC running Linux. But using the ARM crosscompiler suppplied by the manufactor of our embedded device, it gives a segmentation fault just before `catch (...)`.

This problems seems to have a link with [this post](http://groups.google.nl/group/comp.unix.bsd.openbsd.misc/browse_thread/thread/3584ef9ce4a396d9/26e16eb305cb13?hl=nl&ie=UTF-8&q=try+catch+in+thread+gives+segmentation+fault&pli=1) in Google Groups, but I haven't found any solution yet.

The code is compiled using an ARM cross compiler

Any suggestions are still welcome!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *ExecuteThreadMethod(void *AThread);

class Thread
{
  private:
    pthread_t internalThread;
  public:
    void RunSigSegv()
    {
      try
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
          usleep(10000);
        }
      } // <---- Segmentation fault occurs here
      catch(...)
      {
      }
    }

    void Start()
    {
      pthread_attr_t _attr;

      pthread_attr_init(&_attr);
      pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&_attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
      pthread_create (&internalThread, &_attr, ExecuteThreadMethod, this);
    }
};

void *ExecuteThreadMethod(void *AThread)
{
  ((Thread *)AThread)->RunSigSegv();
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

Thread _thread1;
Thread _thread2;
Thread _thread3;
Thread _thread4;

void s()
{
  _thread1.Start();
  _thread2.Start();
  _thread3.Start();
  _thread4.Start();
}

int main(void)
{
  s();
  usleep(5000000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I once encountered a problem like this which was caused by linking with a version of `libstdc++` with no threading support, meaning that all threads shared a common exception handling stack with disastrous consequences.

Make sure the cross-compiler and its libraries were configured with `--enable-threads=posix`.

Comment: This piece of code is compiled without <code>libstdc++</code>. It shouldn't use any of the STL routines (as far as I know).

Comment: @Laurens: It will be included implicitly when linking with `g++`; it's needed for various bits of language support, including exception handling, as well as the Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

Just a diagnostic question: What happens if you don't detach the thread in Start()? You'd have to pthread_join() the threads back in main().

Also, have you considered [Boost's threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html)? That might be more appropriate since you're using C++ rather than C.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it with joinable threads and it makes no difference.